# How to highlight elements according to current event date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I borrowed some code from another question asked on SO, since I couldn't find a script that would do what I want to achieve.

What I'd like to do is highlight a current event based on the date it is assigned, and the following code is not working for an `<td>` element inside a table, a `<div>`, or a `<p>` element.

I would also like to apply the highlight to any ID of the same name, is that possible with what I have now?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title></title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js'></script>
<style>
body {padding: 20px; font-family: sans-serif;}
p {margin-top: 80px; font-size: 11px;}
.active {color: hotpink;
background:#000;
font-weight:bold;
}
</style>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
var TODAY = new Date();
//Individual dates could be organized as objects, but using arrays below seems to be more readable and tidy
var SCHEDULE = {
'some-class': ['May 5 2011', 'June 5 2011'],
'some-class-a': ['May 5 2012', 'June 5 2012'],
'some-class-b': ['May 10 2012', 'June 10 2012'],
'some-class-c': ['December 15 2012', 'December 31 2012'],
'some-class-d': ['May 20 2012', 'June 20 2012'],
'some-class-e': ['December 15 2012', 'December 31 2012']
};
for (var events_ in SCHEDULE) {
console.log('checking ' + events_ + ', dates have to be within the ' + SCHEDULE[events_] + ' range');
if (TODAY >= Date.parse(SCHEDULE[events_][0]) && TODAY <= Date.parse(SCHEDULE[events_][1])) {
console.log(events_ + ' is currently in session!');
document.getElementById(events_).classList.add('active');
}
}
});//]]>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
<li id="some-class">Event 1</li>
<li id="some-class-a">Event 2</li>
<li id="some-class-b">Event 3</li>
<li id="some-class-c">Event 4</li>
<li id="some-class-d">Event 5</li>
<li id="some-class-e">Event 6</li>
</ul>
<p id="some-class-e">Current event here text</p>
<div id="some-class-e">Current event here, more text</div>
<table id="events" border="1">
<tr>
<td>Event 1 (May 16 - Dec 1)</td>
</tr>         
<tr>
<td>Event 2 (May 31 - June 1)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="some-class-e">Current Event (December 15 - December 31)</td>
</tr>               
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jhd7G/2/)

Comment: I don't quite understand the question but one problem I see is that your id's need to be unique. Switch to classes if using more than once.

Comment: the present code only works for the `ul / li` elements and my knowledge of jQuery is limited.

Comment: Thanks for the drive-by.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, `ID`s need to be unique and by making use of `document.getElementById` you will only fetch one.

If you want to use the same identifier (for example, `some-class-e`) more than once you need to make use of a classname instead.

You can get all the elements by classname using `document.getElementsByClassName` and then apply the `active` classname to it.

```
<ul><li class="some-class-e">Event 6</li></ul>
<p class="some-class-e">Current event here text</p>
<div class="some-class-e">Current event here, more text</div>
```

```
var matches = document.getElementsByClassName(events_);
for(var i = 0; i < matches.length; ++i){
  matches[i].classList.add('active');
}
```

[**See it here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/qvFGC/)

---

### UPDATE

A jQuery variant:

```
$.each(SCHEDULE, function(classname, dates) {
  if (TODAY >= Date.parse(dates[0]) && TODAY <= Date.parse(dates[1])) {
    $("." + classname).addClass("active");
  }
});
```

[**There you go.**](http://jsfiddle.net/fSF3V/)

Comment: Note - document.getElementsByClassName is not supported in older versions of IE (<IE8 I think). Search 'getElementsByClassName polyfill' for a working version in all browsers.

Comment: that's ok, mostly for FF and IE7 + users

Comment: and yes you're right about IE7, is not supported. Is there a fix for that?

Comment: I would be more worried about your usage of `classList` though. Easiest way is delegating it to jQuery

Comment: can `classList` be subsituted for something else? as I said, my knowledge of jQuery is very limited.

Comment: @Fred, I added a jQuery variant